# C# REGEX need to be corrected

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace

I'm making a C# regex to find and replace patterns related to html content. 
i need to get all the stuff like that:

```
<table border=0 align=center id=mytable5>
```

corrected like that:

```
<table border="0" align="center" id="mytable5">
```

i tried out this:

```
String pattern = @"\s(?<element>[a-z])=(?<valeur>\d+?[a-z])\s?[\>]";
String replacePattern = "${element}=[\"]${valeur}[\"]";
html = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, replacePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but there is absolutly no effect. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
thank you all

---

Actually King King, there is a problem with your regex

```
<table border=0 align="center" id="mytable5">
```

will give

```
<table border="0" align=""center"" id=""mytable5"">
```

thats why the regex must check this

[a space][a-z]=[a-z0-9][a space or '>']

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/393487

Comment: its not about making the regex understand html here, but its just a pattern remplacement in a string, nothing more. but thanks for your link btw, i like how the letters are leaking at the bottom, nice visual effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
String pattern = @"([a-z]+)=([a-z0-9_-]+)([ >])";
String replacePattern = "${1}=\"${2}\"${3}";
html = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, replacePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

will get

```
<table border=0 align="center" id="mytable5">
```

corrected to this:

```
<table border="0" align="center" id="mytable5">
```

thanks for King King that showed me the path

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = "<table border=0 align=center id=mytable5>";
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"=\s*(\S+?)([ >])", "=\"${1}\"${2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: there is a problem with your regex, please check out my first post i just added whats wrong